# postgresql: relation "table_name" does not exist when trying to CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

I am running this code thru pgAdmin4:

```
CREATE TABLE product(
    code integer, 
    pname varchar(30),
    descr varchar(50),
    utype varchar(30),
    uprice float, 
    manu varchar(30),
    sid integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (code, sid),
    FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES supplier(sid)
);

CREATE TABLE branch(
    bid integer,
    bname varchar(30),
    baddress varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (bid)
);

CREATE TABLE stock(
    code integer,
    bid integer,
    units float,
    PRIMARY KEY (code, bid)
);

CREATE TABLE receipt(
    bid integer,
    rdate date,
    rtime time,
    ptype varchar(30),
    total float,
    PRIMARY KEY (bid, rdate, rtime)
);

CREATE TABLE purchase(
    bid integer,
    rdate date,
    rtime time,
    code integer,
    units float,
    PRIMARY KEY (bid, rdate, rtime, code),
    check (units > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE supplier(
    sid integer,
    sname varchar(30),
    address varchar(50),
    phone numeric (9,0),
    PRIMARY KEY (sid)
);

INSERT INTO product (code, pname, descr, utype, uprice, manu, sid) VALUES
        (987, 'Tomatoes',       'Vegetable',  'Kg',  5.99,  'manufacturer1', 111),
        (876, 'Cucumbers',      'Vegetable',  'Kg',  4.99,  'manufacturer1', 222),
        (765, 'Cornflakes',     'Cornflakes', 'Box', 15.9,  'manufacturer1', 222),

INSERT INTO branch (bid, bname, baddress) VALUES
        (987, 'tal aviv', 'road 1 tel aviv'),
        (878, 'Raanana',  'road 1 raanana'),
        (767, 'Holon',    'road 1 holon');

INSERT INTO stock (code, bid, units) VALUES
        (987, 989, 50),
        (987, 878, 75),
        (987, 767, 100),

INSERT INTO receipt (bid, rdate, rtime, ptype) VALUES
        (989, '2020-3-19', '10:00', 'Cash'),
        (989, '2020-7-16', '12:30', 'Credit'),
        (989, '2020-7-15', '15:35', 'Credit'),

INSERT INTO purchase (bid, rdate, rtime, code, units) VALUES
        (989, '2020-3-18', '10:00', 987, 5),
        (989, '2020-3-18', '10:00', 876, 3),
        (989, '2020-3-18', '10:00', 543, 4),

INSERT INTO supplier (sid, sname, address, phone) VALUES
        (111, 'supplier2', 'road2 tel aviv',  111111111),
        (222, 'supplier3', 'road3 jerusalem', 222222222),
        (333, 'supplier4', 'road2 eilat',     333333333);
```

i am keep getting this message:
**ERROR:  relation "supplier" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01**

The problem is with the **foreign key** in the product table (1st table), i know this because i removed it and it created all the tables with values (i removed some of the values to facilitate the writing).

Not sure if its a syntax error, i tried a couple of ways to solve it but i am clueless, any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously you need to create the `supplier` table **before** you can define a foreign key on it. Re-order your statements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i tried a that option but it keeps consisting that the table does not exsits, you suggest maybe after all the values and tables are created to add that command?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b7fe5514f7d9cb9f83dc50a30d7801b4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create `supplier` table before `product` table as `sid` from product table references to `sid` in supplier table as a foreign key.

Here is the working [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/teN6dRMdzAdfuTaLU5gWsL/0).

```
CREATE TABLE supplier(
    sid integer,
    sname varchar(30),
    address varchar(50),
    phone numeric (9,0),
    PRIMARY KEY (sid)
);

CREATE TABLE product(
    code integer, 
    pname varchar(30),
    descr varchar(50),
    utype varchar(30),
    uprice float, 
    manu varchar(30),
    sid integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (code, sid),
    FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES supplier(sid)
);
```

Comment: works perfectly thanks, i used the demo for that.
In my previous attemps i tried to switch the product and supplier locations but not to put them both lower in the sql query, and thats why i kept getting that error.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add the constraint later (before the insert). This way you don't have to worry about the order of table creation.

```
ALTER TABLE product
ADD FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES supplier(sid);
```